# Android network API request

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, http, client

I often use a similar scheme work with an API project. Can it be made easier, or is there a standard approach?

This class creates an API request:

```
public class ApiRequestCreator {

     private static String TEST_API_REQUEST = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

     public static Request createTestApiRequest(){
         return new Request.Builder()
                .url(TEST_API_REQUEST)
                .build();
     }
}
```

This class execute the request:

```
 public class ApiRequestExecutor {

     private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

     public void run(final Request request, final ApiMethodListener apiMethodListener) {

         new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void ...voids) {
                try {
                     Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                     if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                     return response.body().string();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                apiMethodListener.result(result);
            }

        }.execute();

    }
}
```

For all of this to start:

```
new ApiRequestExecutor().run(ApiRequestCreator.createTestApiRequest(), call_back_interface_here);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good, but in my opinion AsyncTasks are good for single operations - it's not pleasant to make AsyncTask reusable. In my projects I use [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) to download some JSON data from API. This (and similar) library is prepared for making API calls, so it's easier and more ellegant to use for network requests.